# Delete a brightway method, not just deregister

Tags: brightway

I wish to streamline one of my projects by deleting superfluous LCIA methods.

I know that I can deregister methods like this:

```
Method(('superfluous', 'method', 'tuple')).deregister()
```

But according to the docstrings, this will "Remove an object from the metadata store. Does not delete any files."

`Method` objects lack a `delete` method like `Database` objects have.
Is there a sensible way to delete methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting all the default methods would only save around 20 MB, so it is normally not worth worrying about. To delete the actual data, you would need to delete the intermediate pickle and the processed array manually. Their paths are:

```
import brightway2 as bw
import os
my_method = bw.Method(("some", "method"))
# Intermediate pickle, what gets loaded by my_method.load()
os.path.join(bw.projects.dir, "intermediate", my_method.filename + ".pickle")
# Processed array, used in calculations
my_method.filepath_processed()
```